# How to fix transition on tooltips in CSS3?

Tags: css, tooltip, css-transitions

I'm trying to add transition effect to the tooltip "container" so when I hover over the container the tooltip shows. But it also appears when I hover over the tooltip itself. What can I do to stop the hovering transition effect on the tooltip so it shows only when I hover over the container?

```css
/*Styles for the tooltip container*/

.tooltip {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}


/* Styles for the tooltip*/

.tooltip::before {
  content: attr(title);
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: calc(100% + 5px);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}


/* Styles for the arrow*/

.tooltip::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.tooltip:hover::after,
.tooltip:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur 
     adipisicing elit. Minima, ipsa.">tooltip</div>
```

Comment: CSS on its own doesn’t tell us much in most cases, we need to see some HTML you are applying this to as well. [mre]

Comment: Sorry. I just edited it. It's just a div with the class of tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have to negate pointer events with adding `pointer-events: none;` to the pseudo element. Cheers and welcome to SO! :)

```css
/*Styles for the tooltip container*/

.tooltip {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}


/* Styles for the tooltip*/

.tooltip::before {
  content: attr(title);
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: calc(100% + 5px);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* Styles for the arrow*/

.tooltip::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.tooltip:hover::after,
.tooltip:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur 
     adipisicing elit. Minima, ipsa.">tooltip</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't had any idea about the pointer-events property.